# Complex Select Query

Tags: mysql, database

i want implement like fb news feed and i have done following things but i don't know what should be the query to retrive that kind of data

i have these tables

**TABLE : posts**
This table used to store users status 
post_id is AI and primary
username is the userid of user
share is the visibility control if it is public it shareable to everyone or if it shared with list of user then share filed contains share_id of that list.

```
+--------------+---------------+
| col_name     | col_type      |
+--------------|---------------+
| post_id      | INT(11)       |
+--------------|---------------+
| username     |  VARCHAR(50)  |
+--------------|---------------+
| share        |  VARCHAR(50)  |
+--------------|---------------+
| content      |  TEXT         |
+--------------|---------------+
```

**TABLE : share** 
This table store lists of user 
share_id is AI and primary
share_name is name of shareing list.

```
+--------------+---------------+
| col_name     | col_type      |
+--------------|---------------+
| share_id     | INT(11)       |
+--------------|---------------+
| username     |  VARCHAR(50)  |
+--------------|---------------+
| share_name   |  VARCHAR(50)  |
+--------------|---------------+
```

**TABLE : share_member**
This table is child table of `share` which stores list of shared member.

```
+--------------+---------------+
| col_name     | col_type      |
+--------------|---------------+
| smid         | INT(11)       |
+--------------|---------------+
| share_id     |  IMT(11)      |
+--------------|---------------+
| username     |  VARCHAR(50)  |
+--------------|---------------+
```

i want get data of all user who allowed me see.including public.

**EDIT:**

i added one more column to table posts

and then tried this query

```
SELECT p.*, CASE p.share_type when 'public' then "1" when 'list' then if((select count(*) FROM share_member WHERE username='pratik' AND share_id=share)>="1") then "1" END AS allowed FROM posts p
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE IF(share="public",1,0)=1 This query but this is not enough

Comment: You've tagged this with three different database engines, and the choice of engine will affect the answer.  Which one are you actually using?

Comment: Something like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5847a/1)?